# SQL Server Full Text Search Most Common Word Pairs

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2012

I am looking for a way to query for the most common adjacent words and/or most common included words in a document given a set of documents containing a word.

For example, I would like a query that would accept 'windows' and return a list of words that are most commonly found in a document containing 'windows', like 'microsoft' or 'doors'.

I would like to find adjacent words, but I also see a potential need in my application for eventually knowing the most common words also present in the document. An example of that might be 'linux' or 'efficiency'. Those words might not be adjacent to 'windows' but they are likely to be in the same document.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2739391/271351) question which helps me part way, but that only gets me the most common words given all the documents, or a specific document, not a set of documents.